# Why python UDP server is slow in this case? udp clients are getting reply after 5 to 6 seconds.. of course i have 250 client threads attacking server

Tags: python, multithreading, server, udp, delay

I have a UDP server that takes data from clients (250), converts the data into upper case then replies back to the user.

With 250 clients sending the data, the server is replying to all the clients, but the time between sending and receiving data for each client is pretty high around 5 seconds at on average.

Could anyone figure it out why the elapsed time for each client is so high?

### Here is the server code :

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print(sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
while True:
    print(sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print(sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print(sys.stderr, data)
    data = data.upper()
    if data:
        sent = sock.sendto(data, address)
        print(sys.stderr, 'sent %s bytes back to %s' % (sent, address))
```

---

Here is the client code :
On the client end I am creating 250 threads and each thread holds a while loop and they will send the data forever.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
import decimal
from random import randint

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,name=name)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.server_address = ('192.168.1.251', 10000)

    def run(self):
        print(self.name + " Started")
        message = "Hello....i am client : "+self.name
        while True:
            #time.sleep(1)
            time.sleep(decimal.Decimal(randint(1,5) / 10))
            #send data to server
            #print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
            dat_sen_t = time.time()
            sent = self.sock.sendto(message.encode(), self.server_address)
            # Receive response
            #print(sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive')
            data, server = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)
            data = data.decode()
            print(sys.stderr, ' received "%s"' % data +"Tim Taken :"+ (str((time.time() - dat_sen_t))) + ' seconds\n')
            fil.write(self.name+' received "%s"' % data +"Tim Taken :"+ (str((time.time() - dat_sen_t))) + ' seconds\n')

def Main():
    threads = []

    for i in range(250):
        thread_i="Thread"+str(i)
        thread = myThread(thread_i)
        threads += [thread]
        thread.start()

    for x in threads:
        x.join()

    print("Exiting Main Thread ")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fil = open("UDP1_cli_log.txt", "a+")
    Main()
```

---

Client side log file looks like this:
[Client log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOk3F.png)

Comment: server doesn't use threads so every client has to wait.

Comment: yeah i know that.  i have another code which implements threading in server, it works better. But still, if you look into my client log file, the delay time between sending and receiving data for each client is around 6 seconds which is something weird.  The UDP must be too fast and i believe it can deliver at pretty less delay times.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it. There are 3 issues.

1. Printing received data to the console on server end.
2. Logging data to a common file for all 250 cleints
3. The times calculated on client end are not accurate.

**Server printing data to console issue:** : 
Since there is no threading on server end. It is receiving data from 250 clients continuously. So the server needs to listen to clients, receive data and print data to the console. We have only 1 output stream to the console. So server is spending more time in clearing the queued data to the output stream. during this time server is not listening for incoming clients.when i removed these print steps on servers end, the times are drastically improved.

**Logging data to a common file for all 250 cleints:**
you have 250 threads on clients end. all these 250 threads are logging to a same file. So when 1 thread is writing to a file, it puts a lock to that file during this time all other 249 threads are waiting in the line. while writing the data to the file, we are calculating the time as shown below:

```
fil.write(self.name+' received "%s"' % data +"Tim Taken :"+ (str((time.time() - dat_sen_t))) + ' seconds\n')
```

so here we are including the waiting time to get the access to the log file.
if we carefully observe the clients code, we are printing the times to the console and also logging to a file. these 2 will be different. so best solution to log the precise timings of clients is: first save the time difference in your memory and later on log it to a file.

**Times calculated on client end are not accurate:**
On client end, i am calculating times between sending and receiving data. But before sending data there is a step called encoding and after receiving data there is another step called decoding. These encoding and decoding also takes time. So calculate time t1 after sending data to server and then calculate time t2 after receiving data before decoding. don't include these encoding and decoding time for calculating the exact time taken by each client to send data to server and receive reply.

Conclusion: after taking care of these steps. The timings are drastically improved. So python is powerful enough to design a UDP server. All the 250 clients received data with in milliseconds.